# how to access protected routes if the user is admin or not in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

i'm trying to protect routes if isAdmin is false

this is how i protect the routes if theres's token in browser

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const hasToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // Route requires authentication
    if (hasToken) {
      // User is authenticated, allow access to the route
      next();
    } else {
      // User is not authenticated, redirect to the login page
      next('/login');
    }
  } else {
    // Route does not require authentication
    next();
  }
});
{
  path: "/rex",
  name: "rex",
 route
  meta: {
    requiresAuth: true
  },
  component: () =>
    import("../components/rex.vue")
},
```

the above protect the route if there a token ,now how do i protect my routes that only an Admin can see, in my store i'm getting isAdmin :true
[image]

please how can i go about this, they can both have token but restrict routes if user isAdmin

Answer (score 0):

If your app is SPA (and not SSR), you can just import your store and access its data in router navigation guards:

Vuex:

```
// store.js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
 state() {
   isAdmin: false
 }
})

// router.js
import store from "./store"


router.beforeEach(() => {
  if (store.state.isAdmin) // do something
})
```

Pinia:

```
// useUserStore.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
  const isAdmin = ref(false)
  
  return { isAdmin }
})

// router.js
import { useUserStore } from "./useUserStore"


router.beforeEach(() => {
  const userStore = useUserStore()
  if (userStore.isAdmin) // do something
})
```

Comment: so how do i access it i my routes?

Comment: the same way you do it with your user token. The only difference is that you get the token from localStorage while isAuth can be accessed from an imported store

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this on the route you want to protect:

In your routes file first get the "isAdmin" from local storage

```
const isAdmin = localStorage.getItem('isAdmin');
```

Then in the route do this:

```
{
  path: "/idAdminRoute",
  name: "admin-route",
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      if(isAdmin){
          next()
      }
      return false
    },
  component: () =>
    import("../components/admin.vue")
},
```

this will get applied to all the child routes as well.

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: Can you please tell me the issue you are facing while implementing this